# Oracle Data Modeler: How to create view my_view start with id = 0 connect by prior id = p_id

Tags: oracle10g, data-modeling

I have a table hierarhy as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts
    (
     id NUMBER  NOT NULL ,
     p_id NUMBER ,
     acc_num NUMBER
    )
```

I can create view as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
 SELECT level lvl, id, p_id
   FROM accounts
   START WITH id = 0 CONNECT BY PRIOR id = p_id;
```

I can't create this view in Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler. How can I do this task?

Comment: Please post the ORA error you're receiving

Comment: My steps in Data Modeler:
* Add view to relational diagram
* Open view properties
* Select Query Builder
* Add table 'accounts' to build area
* Select columns to add to query

Then I try to type my query in SQL area as above. When I press Apply button I got 
`SELECT Level lvl, accounts.id, accounts.p_id FROM accounts CONNECT BY` and it is nothing more.

Comment: Finnaly, I can't solve this problem. I done this by separate SQL-script with 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW'.